# PowerShell looping

Tags: powershell

New buddy in PowerShell. I am looking for script for create 2 files but create 1 second file after every 20 first files.

Example: for each 100 first files created, 5 second files should be created.

How to do that?

Thanks in advance.

```
$every=20
$total=100
for($i=0; $i -lt $total; $i++){
if($i % $every -eq ($every - 1)){
%{1..100} |foreach {

Copy-Item -Path \\source-TEST.pdf -Destination \\destination\test_pdf\123456-7209-TEST$_.pdf  -Recurse -force}

}
%{1..20} |foreach {

Copy-Item -Path \\source-TEST.tiff -Destination \\destination\test_tiff\123456-7209-TEST$_.tiff  -Recurse -force}
}
```

Comment: [1] i confess that i don't understand your idea. would you please try to restate it? [2] what have you tried? what did not work as expected?

Comment: Hi Lee, I have 2 individual powershell scrips (.tiff,.pdf) to create multiple files. I am using foreach loop like  this  %(1...100) |foreach  {My file creation scrips} and use $ variable for sequence file names. Now my requirement combined two scripts and build the condition like every 20 .tiff files 1 pdf file should be create. I did not have much knowledge what powershell loops I am using to archive this. Please suggest me the options.

Comment: @rameshbabu - when you want to reply to a comment, use the same `@UserName` at the start of the comment [similar to what i did in this message] to have S-O notify the person.

Comment: @rameshbabu - thank you for the added info! [*grin*] please add that to your Question so others can find it easily. it looks like `Mathias R. Jessen` has an Answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `%` modulo operator in a `for` loop to "cycle" every 20 times:

```
$every = 20
$total = 100

$count1 = 1
$count2 = 1

for($i = 0; $i -lt $total; $i++){
  if($i % $every -eq ($every - 1)){
    Copy-Item -Path \\source-TEST.tiff -Destination \\destination\test_tiff\123456-7209-TEST$count2.tiff -Recurse -Force
    $count2++
  }
  Copy-Item -Path \\source-TEST.pdf -Destination \\destination\test_pdf\123456-7209-TEST$count1.pdf -Recurse -Force
  $count1++
}
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response.

I update my script as per your response but some how its not working as expected.Please chk and suggest.

$every=20
$total=100
for($i=0; $i -lt $total; $i++){
if($i % $every -eq ($every - 1)){
%{1..100} |foreach {

Copy-Item -Path \\source-TEST.pdf -Destination \\destination\test_pdf\123456-7209-TEST$_.pdf  -Recurse -force}

}
%{1..20} |foreach {

Copy-Item -Path \\source-TEST.tiff -Destination \\destination\test_tiff\123456-7209-TEST$_.tiff  -Recurse -force}
}

Comment: Don't put code blocks in the comment section since it's hard for folks to follow. Move this back to your original post as an update.

Comment: @rameshbabu Create _1_ file at a time inside the `for` loop, I updated my answer to show how to run your example

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen appreciated your help. script working as expected.

Comment: @rameshbabu great to hear. If my answer solves your problem, please consider marking it "accepted" by clicking the checkmark on the left